# How to call a subfunction in a different script and div element

Tags: javascript

I have some code like this:

```
function A() {
  this.Test = (function () {
    // some code here
    function B() {
      // some code here
    }
    function c() {
      // some code here
    }
    return { B: B };
  })();
}
```

I want to call `B` function in a different script.  I added this code:

```
var testing = new A();
```

to the new script and call it:

```
testing.Test.B();
```

However it doesn't work.
And also I need to call function `B` in a `div` element:

```
<div onmousedown="testing.Test.B();">
...
</div>
```

But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: where you add `return {
    B: B
}`?

Comment: @Grundy before `})();` after function c

Comment: so, what you mean when say: `it doesn't work`?

Comment: In order for `testing.Test.anything` to work, `testing.Test` must return an object with a property called `anything`.  Right now it doesn't return, well, anything.

Comment: @James, from OP: _I want to call B function in a different sript. I tried adding

`return {
    B: B
}`_

Comment: @Grundy, Sorry it works After deleting `testing.Test.B();` from div! But I need to add this function to the div element. any idea?

Comment: @mac can you provide where you declare this function and create `testing` object, and where in html your div? if you add to div, do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: @Grundy I have this function in a javascript file and want to call it in an external html file.

Comment: @mac, show how, and more main, where you include your _js_ file and where your div

Answer (score 0):

try it as testing.Test(); instead of testing.Test.B();

Comment: Thanks, But I want to call only function B.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing seems to work for me; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Lrxdoa/).

```js
var A = function () {
 alert('A!');
 this.Test = (function () {
  var B = function () {
   alert('B!');
  };
  return {
   B: B
  }
 })();
};

window.testing = new A(); // var testing =... will work as well if the whole code isn't wrapped in another function.
testing.Test.B();
```